# Column values not changed after edit the coulmn in GRIDX

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojox.charting, dojo.gridx

Am using Dojo Gridx in my project. These are my columns names
      id, field1, field2, active status

I have a assignment, when click column active status need to change the active status value, column icon and field1, field2 values.

For example : if active status values is 'Y' when I click, then I want to change the value of field1, field2 and change active status icon. I can achieve this functionality with the help of below mentioned code.

But here the problem is, field1 is editable, if I click active status column with out edit the field1 the below mentioned code working fine. After I edited, if I click active status column below mentioned code is not working. But values changes in server side, DB side working fine. I don't know what problem please some one make me to understand. I have attached my code for your reference.

require(["dojo/request","dojo/i18n!RW/nls/appResources"], function(request,bundle){
                request.get("/RW/rest/"+that.resourcePath,{handleAs : 'J'}).then(
                    function(J){

```
                    that.JGloData=J;
                    var dataToPopulate = {
                            identifier: 'id',
                            items: that.JGloData
                    };  
                    review.app.defectClassAE.partStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                        data : dataToPopulate
                    });

                    review.app.defectClassAE.partStructure = [
                    {
                        field : 'id',
                        name : that.J.defect_id,
                        width : '5%',
                        dataType : 'string',
                        alwaysEditing : false,
                        editable : false,
                    },
                    {
                        field : 'field1',
                        name : that.J.defect_class,
                        width : '25%',
                        dataType : 'string',
                        alwaysEditing : false,
                        editable : true,
                        editor : dijit.form.Textarea,
                    },

                    {
                        field : 'field2',
                        name : that.J.defect_activate_date,
                        width : '18%',
                        dataType : 'string',
                        alwaysEditing : false,
                        editable : false,
                    },
                    {
                        field : 'field3',
                        name : that.J.defect_deactivate_date,
                        width : '18%',
                        dataType : 'string',
                        alwaysEditing : false,
                        editable : false,
                    },

                    { field: 'activeStatus', name: bundle.RT_QLIST_ACTIVATE, filterable: false, width: '20%' ,editable : false,
                        widgetsInCell: true,
                        decorator: function(){
                            return "<button data-dojo-type='dijit/form/Button' data-dojo-attach-point='btnactivate' data-dojo-props='showLabel: false' type='button'>Activate</button>";
                            //return "<div data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button' data-dojo-attach-point='btnactivate'></div>";
                            },
                        setCellValue: function(gridData, storeData, cellWidget){
                            if(gridData == "Y"){
                                cellWidget.btnactivate.set('iconClass', "rtIcondeactivateReviewType");
                            }else{
                                cellWidget.btnactivate.set('iconClass', "rtIconactivateReviewType");
                            }
                            (function(cellWidget){

                                dojo.connect(cellWidget.btnactivate,"onClick",function(){
                                    //var that = this;
                                    var rawData = cellWidget.cell.row.rawData();
                                    var cell   =  cellWidget.cell;
                                        var DI="";
                                        var activeStatus="";
                                        DI=rawData.DI;
                                        activeStatus=rawData.activeStatus;
                                        if(DI!=null && DI!=""){
                                            require(["dojo/request","dojo/i18n!RW/nls/appResources"], function(request,bundle){
                                                request.get("/RW/rest/"+that.resourcePath+"/defectActOrDea/"+DI,{handleAs : 'J'}).then(
                                                          function(J){

                                                              if(activeStatus=='Y' || activeStatus==""){
                                                                  var deactvalues = {
                                                                    'activeStatus' : 'N',
                                                                     'field3':that.getTodayDate(),
                                                                     'field2':""
                                                                    };
                                                                  cell.row.setRawData(deactvalues);
                                                              that.set('iconClass', "rtIcondeactivateReviewType");
                                                              }
                                                              else{
                                                                  var actvalues = {
                                                                            'activeStatus' : 'Y',
                                                                             'field2':that.getTodayDate(),
                                                                             'field3':""
                                                                            };
                                                                          cell.row.setRawData(actvalues);
                                                              that.set('iconClass', "rtIconactivateReviewType")
                                                              }
                                                          },
                                                          function(error){
                                                              showErrorNotification(that.J.defect_act_deact_error);
                                                          }
                                                    );
                                            });
                                        }

                                });
                            })(cellWidget);
                            }
                        },
                    ];
```

Comment: Please some one help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 'getCellWidgetConnects' for binding events to cell widgets. Also make sure you have your grid model saved after editing.